# Reactjs call Cakephp Api both on localhost : Cross-Origin Request Blocked (CORS)

Tags: reactjs, cakephp-2.0

I am new to react js. So for the learning sake i installed it on my system which is running on localhost with port 3000. i have also installed cakephp version 2.98 on xampp which is again running on localhost but with port 8082.
Now when i am trying to call fetch operations from react js to my cakephp api which is on localhost:8082 i am recieving error msg :

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8082/cakephp298/users/apitest. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

i tried adding crossorigin attribute in script tags in my index file but its not working.
I am looking for a solution to add headers to fetch operations.

------here's my code for react ----

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.clicksfile = this.clicksfile.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div id="mc_embed_signup">
        <input name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email address" required type="email" />
        <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required />

        <button onClick={ this.clicksfile } className="primary-btn hover d-inline-flex align-items-center">
          <span className="mr-10">Go</span><span className="lnr lnr-arrow-right" /></button>
        <div className="info" />
      </div>


    );
  }

  clicksfile(e) {
    fetch('http://localhost:8082/cakephp298/users/apitest').then(response => response.json()).then(response => {

      console.log('details fetched successfully they are');
      console.log(response);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log('There is some error ashish');
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an issue with react, but instead a restriction the CakePHP application is applying.

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that uses
>   additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application
>   running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected
>   resources from a server at a different origin.

What this means is that you cannot send requests to other domains or ports without explicitly permitting it. In this case, you are running react on `http://localhost:3000/` and you are attempting to request `http://localhost:8082/`.

To enable this, you will need to add the following HTTP response header to your endpoint on the CakePHP application.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

In CakePHP, it will look like this

```
$response = $response->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
```

You can read more about this [HTTP header here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) and how to set headers in [CakePHP here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-headers)

Comment: But how to do it with Login as you do not receive any response from server yet? Or is it to handle the login response that you need the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`? Cause I have it in my CORS Middleware in Laravel.

Comment: @KeitelDOG I'm not sure I understand the question. You will not get a response from a server if you request from another origin and haven't added the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to permit that origin.

Comment: I understand it perfectly now. But in my case I was having problems because ReactJS sent a preflight request first with method `OPTIONS` that is served to return mainly headers to see if hostname has the right to use the server response data. But Laravel was not setting headers in api header middleware with that particular method `OPTIONS`. So I added it in global middleware for that request method. If ReactJS has made the simple request only which would be `POST` for Login, it would have received the proper response headers allowing the origin.